# Does django set_cookie method encrypts the cookie value?

Tags: django, cookies, encryption

That's what I want to know. If I have to encrypt the cookie value manually or if the method does it automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cookies, you likely care more about signing (can someone modify or forge data) than encryption ( can someone read it).

That said, according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions) documentation if you use cookie based sessions, django does support it since version 1.4